# Calling out a class giving me problems (bad class - class file contains wrong class)

Tags: java

Here is the error i'm getting:

```
 airfoilNumber.java:5: error: cannot access airfoil
    private airfoil myAirfoil = new airfoil();
            ^
  bad class file: ./airfoil.class
    class file contains wrong class: airfoil.airfoil
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Here is my main class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class airfoilNumber
{
    private airfoil myAirfoil = new airfoil();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner numNaca1 = new Scanner(System.in); //make a scanner and prompt user for their desired NACA number
    System.out.println("What is your NACA number?"); //prompt user for NACA number
    int numNaca = numNaca1.nextInt(); //apply the number to numNaca
    new airfoil(numNaca); //call out airfoil class and run calculations


    }
}
```

Here is my calculator class:

```
package airfoil;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class airfoil

{   

    private static final int numOfCoord = 250;
    double dx = 1

.0 / numOfCoord;

private double      m;      // maximum camber in % of chord
private double      p;      // chordwise position of max ord., 10th of chord
private double      t;      // thickness in % of the cord

private String      nacaNum;        // NACA number - 4 digits
private double[][]  coordinates;    // Coordinates of the upper half or lower half of the airfoil
private double[][]  meanLine;       // mean line coordinates

public airfoil(String number) {

    nacaNum = number;
    m = Double.parseDouble(nacaNum.substring(0,1)) / 100.0;
    p = Double.parseDouble(nacaNum.substring(1,2)) / 10.0;
    t = Double.parseDouble(nacaNum.substring(2,4)) / 100.0;

    meanLine = new double[2][numOfCoord];  // x values row 0, y values row 1

    // x upper = row 0, 
    // y upper = row 1,
    // x lower = row 2,
    // y lower = row 3
    coordinates = new double [4][numOfCoord];

    System.out.println("NACA: " + nacaNum);
    System.out.println("Number of coordinates: " + numOfCoord);

    calcMeanLine();
    calcAirfoil();

}

/*
 * Calculates the values for the mean line forward of the maximum
 * ordinate and aft of the maximum ordinate.  
 */
private void calcMeanLine() {

    double x = dx;
    int j = 0;

    // fwd of max ordinate
    while (x <= p) {
        meanLine[0][j] = x;
        meanLine[1][j] = (m / (p * p))*(2*p*x - (x*x));
        x += dx;
        j++;
    }

    // aft of max ordinate
    while (x <= 1.0 + dx) {
        meanLine[0][j] = x;
        meanLine[1][j] = (m / ((1 - p) * (1 - p))) *
                     ((1 - 2*p) + 2*p*x - x * x);
        x += dx;
        j++;
    }
}  // end calcMeanLine

/*
 * Calculate the upper and lower coordinates of the airfoil surface.
 */
private void calcAirfoil() {

    double theta;       // arctan(dy_dx)
    double dy;          // derivative of mean line equation
    double yt, ml;      // thickness and meanline values, respectively
    double x = dx;      // x-value w.r.t. chord
    int j = 0;          // counter for array

    // calculate upper/lower surface coordinates fwd of max ordinate
    while (x <= p) {

        dy = (m / (p*p)) * (2*p - 2*x);
        theta = Math.atan(dy);
        yt = thicknessEQ(x);
        ml = meanLine[1][j];

        // upper surface coordinates;
        coordinates[0][j] = x - yt * Math.sin(theta);
        coordinates[1][j] = ml + yt * Math.cos(theta);

        // lower surface coordinates
        coordinates[2][j] = x + yt*Math.sin(theta);
        coordinates[3][j] = ml - yt * Math.cos(theta);

        x += dx;
        j++;

    }

    // calculate the coordinates aft of max ordinate
    while (x <= 1.0 + dx) {

        dy = (m / ((1 - p) * (1 - p))) * ((2 * p) - (2 * x));
        theta = Math.atan(dy);

        yt = thicknessEQ(x);
        ml = meanLine[1][j];

        // upper surface coordinates;
        coordinates[0][j] = x - yt * Math.sin(theta);
        coordinates[1][j] = ml + yt * Math.cos(theta);

        // lower surface coordinates
        coordinates[2][j] = x + yt * Math.sin(theta);
        coordinates[3][j] = ml - yt * Math.cos(theta);

        x += dx;
        j++;
    }

    System.out.println("j = " + j);

} // end calcAirfoil

/*
 * Thickness equation
 */
private double thicknessEQ(double x) {

    return ((t / 0.2) * (0.2969 * Math.sqrt(x) - (0.126 * x) - 
            (0.3526 * x * x) + (0.28430 * x * x * x) - 
            (0.1015 * x * x * x * x)));
}

public String toString() {

    String str = "";
    NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

    System.out.println("Xu\tYu\tXl\tYl");

        for (int j = 0; j < numOfCoord; j++) {
            str += df.format(coordinates[0][j]) + "\t" + 
                   df.format(coordinates[1][j]) + "\t" +
                   df.format(coordinates[2][j]) + "\t" + 
                   df.format(coordinates[3][j]) + "\n";
        }

    return str;
}

/*
 * Return the coordinates array
 */
public double[][] getCoordinates() { return coordinates; }
public int getSize() { return numOfCoord; }

} // end Airfoil class
```

Here is what i've tried:

Moving the airfoil.class file around from place to place to get it to work

use "new airfoil ("");" by itself, still gives me the same error

used any other type of code to call out my calculator class, same error.

I don't know what else to change. I don't know what it's telling me about "Wrong class airfoil.airfoil", that might be able to lead me to the solution.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You have messed up your directory structure. Your class `airfoil` needs to be in a package (which is, on the filesystem, a **subdirectory**)  `airfoil`.

Comment: It is in a package. At the top before importing anything I've put it in package airfoil. Have I not done that correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is in a package, but is is also in a **subdirectory** called airfoil?

Comment: You should put your class in a package, and make your classname start with uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following class structure:

```
package airfoil;

public class airfoil {
   ...
}
```

```
public class airfoilNumber {
   ...
}
```

This needs to be reflected on the file system like this:

```
MyProject                     Project's top level directory
    +-airfoilNumber.java
    +-airfoil                 directory for "airfoil" package
        +-airfoil.java
```

In addition, you then need to import `airfoil.airfoil` in your `airfoilNumber` class:

```
import airfoil.airfoil;

public class airfoilNumber {
}
```

With this setup, you can compile the two classes from within the project's top level directory with

```
C:> javac *.java
```

As a side comment, class names should start with uppercase letters. I kept the names from the question since casing mismatches between the `class` definition and its containing `.java` file can lead to other issues which are difficult to track, at least on MS Windows.

Once that is done, you need to fix the constructors of your `airfoil` class. There is currently only one constructor which takes a `String` argument, but you call it as follows:

```
private airfoil myAirfoil = new airfoil();   
// does not compile - no non-arg constructor available

...

new airfoil(numNaca);    
// does not compile - numNaca is int, constructor expects String
```

Comment: it's telling me that package airfoil does not exist. I added `package airfoil` in airfoilNumber, for now it's telling me that it cannot find symbol at every iteration of "airfoil" in the airfoilNumber class.

Comment: No no, your `airfoilNumber` class is in the default package (no `package` statement). You **must** have a directory structure which reflects the package structure. (Note that using the default package is discouraged, but you should now first focus on getting your current source to compile before fixing other stuff).

Comment: Right right, thank you. It's compiled fine now. I changed my scanner file around a little so it fits in with the calculator class, and it compiles fine now. The calculator class was giving me a problem - `exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`, i fixed it with, like you said, removing the package from my main class. The whole thing compiles fine now. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

error is in:

```
new airfoil(numNaca); //call out airfoil class and run calculations
```

delete this line and call:

```
myAirfoil(numNaca);
```

new airfoil make new instance of youre class, not run calculations.
New instance exist in code, see line:

```
private airfoil myAirfoil = new airfoil();
```

and acces to this is myAirfoil.

Comment: Did you read in the question that the error **is** at `private airfoil myAirfoil = new airfoil();`?

Comment: I dont know what is with paths and others in his project, I see evident error in "new airfoil(numNaca);", thats all.

Comment: Yeah, still having the same problem with 'private airfoil myAirfoil = new airfoil();'. Thank you anyways!

Comment: What is main class in package? airfoilNumber? not airfoil?